# Detect the end of an HTTP request (Java socket) easiest way?

Tags: java, sockets

I have to use Java sockets to send and receive HTTP requests (I have to!). So I'm looking for a solution that takes into account `content-length` and `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, etc... to decide when the HTTP request has ended.

Here is an example of what I came up with so far:

```
    public String getWebpage()
    {
        try{

            _out.print("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n");
            _out.flush();

            String fullRequest = "";
            String line = null;
            while (( line = _in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                fullRequest += line + "\r\n";
                if(isFullRequest(fullRequest))
                {
                    System.out.println(fullRequest);
                    return fullRequest;
                }
            }            

        }catch(Exception e){}

        return null;
    }

    private boolean isFullRequest(String request)
    {
        return request.contains("\r\n\r\n") //Make sure we have the headers
            && request.contains("</html>"); //Make sure we have the html
    }
```

My `isFullRequest()` method is a very cheap way to detect the end of the request, but isn't reliable.

Instead of reinventing the wheel and spending countless hours into debugging, I'm asking if there's already a Class or Method already included in Java that does exactly what I need ? Without extra unnecessary jar dependencies ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use an existing HTTP library it is much easier to make a HTTP/1.0 request only so that you don't get a chunked response (chunked is only defined for HTTP/1.1). Also don't use keep-alive, which is implicit with HTTP/1.1 but not with HTTP/1.0. In summary, do your request like this:

```
GET /page HTTP/1.0
Host: hostname
```

And then simply read the response until end of data. Since keep-alive is by default off with HTTP/1.0 the server will close the connection after the response is done and since HTTP/1.0 does not support chunked you don't need to worry about this too.

Comment: Thank you ! This kinda solves my problem for now, but maybe it's not very reliable either as it could cause some issues in the long run.. (if there's any such thing as HTTP/1.0 server incompatibility or Bot detection or protection, etc..)

Comment: If you want to look and behave more like a real browser it is much more complex, because you need to support not only HTTP/1.1 with chunked, but also gzip and deflate content-encoding. And even then it will be easy to distinguish your requests from desktop browsers because of lack of JavaScript, not loading included resources like CSS, images, fonts, not sending cookies back and much more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to read a chunked response. This way you don't have to worry about detecting the end of the request.

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
byte[] b=new byte[512*1024];
int len;
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);

while((len=in.read(b))!=-1){
   out.write(b,0,len);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
```

If you want to get the content-lenght you can try :

```
long contentLength = uc.getContentLengthLong()
```

It will works only if `content-length` header is known.

If it's unknown there is another way (not my favourite though...). Read the stream once just to know the content-length.
I used that on a project where it was mandatory to draw progress bar while downloading the content of a page.

```
long max = uc.getContentLengthLong();
if(max==-1){
    max=0;
    if(in.markSupported()){
        in.mark(1000000000);    //max nb of bytes to be read
        while((len=in.read(b))!=-1){
            max+=len;
        }
        in.reset();
    }
}
```